# Excel VBA Fill Table(ListObject) Column With Result of Operation Between Other Table Columns

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, I cannot find a way to fill a column(ListColumns) in a Table(ListObjects) with an operation on two or more of the table's columns using the index number instead of using the headers in a string. So for example, I know this works when using :

```
lo.ListColumns("Spread").DataBodyRange = "=[Current]-[Historic]"
```

But say "Spread" is column 10, and "Current" is column 5 and "Historic" is column 7. Is there a way to do something like the following to populate the column? I know this does not work, but am hoping there is something similar that does as I have tried various methods and cannot find it in a search.

```
lo.ListColumns(10).DataBodyRange = lo.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange - _ 
                                   lo.ListColumns(10)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lo.ListColumns(10).DataBodyRange = "=[" & lo.ListColumns(5).Name & "]-[" & lo.ListColumns(7).Name & "]"
```

Comment: Dangerous. Someone later inserts or deletes a Table column, and the macro does the wrong thing. Best not hardcode references into VBA like this.

Comment: While I agree wholeheartedly, the question was quite clear and I chose to believe OP knew what he/she was doing.

Comment: Yeah, I realise you gave the op exactly what they asked for. It's just that what they asked for might be hazardous to their health. In cases like this I like to explicitly point out the pitfalls of what they're asking to them, and to anyone else whom Google brings here in future. Might save someone an embarrassing, career-limiting mistake in future.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you want to use an INDEX rather than the column header? Using hard coded index numbers doesn't make for robust code...it means that if you (or someone else) later change the layout of your table, you have to go through your code and amend those hard coded references. Which is precisely what the ListObject reference was designed to avoid (both in terms of VBA and Formulas).

It's far better to use Column headers, like in your example. If there's a chance that someone will change the column names, then set up a Named Range to point at the ListColumns concerned, and reference those named ranges in your code.

If all you want to do is find the INDEX number for some reason, then just do something like this:

```
Dim lo as ListObject
Dim lc as ListColumn

On Error Resume Next
Set lc = lo.ListColumns("sName")
On Error GoTo 0
```

...and then you can test if it was found

```
If Not lc Is Nothing Then Msgbox(lc.Index)
```